# using console on VS for JS

Tags: javascript, console

I'm super new to the coding world, and I cannot even figure out how to use the console on VS for JavaScript. I clicked debug and run, it gives me this [Cannot find runtime 'node' on PATH. Is 'node' installed?] every time. And I want to learn vanilla JS first, so I don't know no why I should use node.js debugging

Comment: What do you mean by VS? If you're completely new, consider just opening a web browser and typing stuff in to start with

Comment: Do you want to write programs that run on your computer? Then write code for node.js which you will have to install. Or do you want to write code that should run in a web page? Then learn javascript in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed node.js yet?
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Simply install the applicable version and then restart your computer. From there you should be able to access node from the vscode console/terminal.

As a side note, even if you're just learning basic javascript I'd suggest learning it on vscode because it's important to get familiar with the environment. You also gain access to many useful features that you will 100% need down the road.

Comment: 0


I did what you said and it worked! but my original question was is it okay to use node.js terminal if I want to learn Vanilla JS? If not, what can I do to set up on vscode? thank you

Comment: @Hahahhahahh Since "vanilla js" does not have any IO routines, you need to choose *some* runtime to do anything useful with it.

Comment: Yes. Within vscode you can work on vanilla javascript which is pretty much just javascript without any 'extensions' or better known as libraries. Vscode will let you do anything from small to big. You can get started by just creating a new file (filename.js) and practicing in there.